# Emulating Real Networking Environments

Tags: c#, .net, networking, latency

I am developing a TCP multiplayer game. I am after testing my game in an environment that simulates high latency, packet loss, etc...

The game is written with C#, I am using visual studio 2013 .net 4.5.2.

What would be the best solution for this? I preferably want to be able to emulate bad networking conditions while the program is being debugged. When I debug the game both the server and client programs run, I connect to the server using the client using the 127.0.0.1 callback.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is an application of [traffic shaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping). I've never found a good *free* tool to do this directly on Windows, but there are various commercial options and other alternatives out there. Here are some examples:

- [SoftPerfect Bandwidth Manager](http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/) - a simple tool to limit the bandwidth use of a particular process
- [OpenWrt](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/packet.scheduler/packet.scheduler) - customize your router to do the traffic shaping
- [BusinessCom Traffic Engineering Server](http://www.bctes.com/software-only-solution.html) - high-end solution

You could also use any number of Linux utilities to do this if you have a Linux machine configured as a network gateway (i.e. a very expensive router). The nice thing about that approach (or using a similar utility on Windows, if you can find one) is that you can script it to programmatically reduce the bandwidth at specific points.

Lots of different approaches are possible here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Write a batch file that uses a loop and ping to flood the other clients in your environment.